# Spree make product in some order , like middle , top and bottom

Tags: spree

I want product in some specific orders , so to achieve this it would be good if I add one column in product table with name position and order it accordingly or there are any other way to do it please help

Comment: An example of what you want?

Comment: suppose you have three product and you want to manage like first order should show in the top , second in the bottom and third in the middle

Comment: You need to add a column on the products table to do that. Then customise to your like

Comment: Yahh that I know I mentioned that , I was asking is there any other way to do it